# Quick java generics question

Tags: java, generics

I don't think I really understand Java generics. What's the difference between these two methods? And why does the second not compile, with the error shown below.

Thanks

```
static List<Integer> add2 (List<Integer> lst) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> res = lst.getClass().newInstance();
    for (Integer i : lst) res.add(i + 2);
    return res;
}
```

.

```
static <T extends List<Integer>> T add2 (T lst) throws Exception {
    T res = lst.getClass().newInstance();
    for (Integer i : lst) res.add(i + 2);
    return res;
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types
  required: T
  found:    capture#1 of ? extends java.util.List
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the error message; who says an application can't compile java files on the fly? Actually lots of apps do! The error is clear: the method can't be compiled; and the question is clear, why can't it compile. @Bruno did not answer that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second method to compile, you have to cast the result of `newInstace()` to `T`:

```
static <T extends List<Integer>> T add2 (T lst) throws Exception {
  T res = (T) lst.getClass().newInstance();
  for (Integer i : lst) res.add(i + 2);
  return res;
}
```

Regarding the difference between the two methods, let's forget about the implementation, and consider only the signature.

After the code is compiled, both methods will have exactly the same signature (so the compiler would give an error if the have the same name). This happens because of what is called **type erasure**.

In Java, all the type parameters disappear after compilation. They are replaced by the most generic possible raw type. In this case, both methods will be compiled as `List add2(List)`.

Now, this will show the difference between the two methods:

```
class Main {
  static <T extends List<Integer>> T add1(T lst) { ... }
  static List<Integer> add2(List<Integer> lst) { ... }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> l1 = add1(l);
    ArrayList<Integer> l2 = add2(l); // ERROR!
  }
}
```

The line marked as `// ERROR!` won't compile.

In the first method, `add1`, the compiler knows that it can assign the result to a variable of type `ArrayList<Integer>`, because the signature states that the return type of the method is exactly the same as that of the parameter. Since the parameter is of type `ArrayList<Integer>`, the compiler will infer `T` to be `ArrayList<Integer>`, which will allow you to assign the result to an `ArrayList<Integer>`.

In the second method, all the compiler knows is that it will return an instance of `List<Integer>`. It cannot be sure that it will be an `ArrayList<Integer>`, so you have to make an explicit cast, `ArrayList<Integer> l2 = (ArrayList<Integer>) add2(l);`. Note that this won't solve the problem: you are simply telling the compiler to stop whining and compile the code. You will still get an warning (*unchecked cast*), which can be silenced by annotating the method with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Now the compiler will be quiet, but you might still get a `ClassCastException` at runtime!

Answer (score 3):

The first one is specified to accept a List<Integer> and return a List<Integer>. List being an interface, the implication is that an instance of some concrete class that implements List is being passed as a parameter and an instance of some other concrete class that implements List is returned as a result, without any further relationship between these two classes other than that they both implement List.

The second one tightens that up: it is specified to accept some class that implements List<Integer> as a parameter, and return an instance of exactly that same class or a descendant class as the result.

So for example you could call the second one like so:

```
ArrayList list; // initialization etc not shown
ArrayList result = x.add2(list);
```

but not the first, unless you added a typecast.

What use that is is another question. ;-)

@Bruno Reis has explained the compile error.

Answer (score 1):

> And why does the second not compile, with the error shown below.

The error shown is *actually* reporting that you have tried to **run code** that failed to compile.  It is a better idea to configure your IDE to not run code with compilation errors.  Or if you insist on letting that happen, at least report the actual compilation error together with the line number, etc.

Comment: @Luigi Plinge You can believe it if it says there is a compiler error. Warnings is another kettle of fish ... that's why they are warnings.

Comment: @EJP I don't believe the IDE many times. My IntelliJ, running on either OpenJDK or Sun's JDK on Ubuntu (all the latest releases), sometimes it gets high and goes totally crazy on a huge project, and starts showing completely non-sense errors in my code. If I cut-and-paste the line showing the error, the IDE will then see that the code is correct...

Comment: Also, I'm starting not to believe the compiler anymore. Sun's compiler is very buggy when it comes to generics! It complains about totally valid code that get's compiled by Eclipse's compiler without even a warning !

Comment: @Bruno Reis - that might really be a bug in the Eclipse compiler ... accepting invalid code.  Make sure that you have up-to-date versions of both compilers.

Comment: @Stephen actually it is a bug in Sun's compiler, reported and accepted a loooong time ago, but still not fixed, as usual in Java. http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6932571

Comment: @Stephen C: Sun's java compiler is not an authority, it's not the specification. If it rejects code, it does not necessarily means that the code is invalid (although it is very likely). Take a look at the link in my comment above for an example. I happened to face the bug in some production code I was writing. I had to write some ugly workarounds for it to compile! There are lots of other bugs related to generics.

Comment: The bug is closed as "fixed in Java 7 (build 109)" which was released to the public in September 2010.  Given that the bug was opened in March 2010, your "looong time ago" claim is an exaggeration.  Also, I never claimed that the Sun compiler was perfect.  I simply stated that a discrepancy between the Eclipse and Sun compilers is not *necessarily* a bug in the Sun compiler.

Comment: @Stephen C: Java 7 (build 109) is not for production environment. What they should have done is release a bugfix to the production compiler. Also, this might be one the fastest bugs fixed by Sun, I'm really impressed by how fast they closed it, "only" 6 months. The norm would be some years. And yes, the discrepancy is not necessarily a bug in Sun's compiler; however, I'd assume, at first, before investigating, that it's a bug in Sun's compiler, from my past experience.

Comment: Oh. Looks like we won't have production-ready Java 7 today. In the official release date, they will release a new RC (build 147), according to http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/java_7_d_day_is . I wouldn't consider the bug really fixed until a bugfix is released in a production version!

Answer (score 1):

> "I don't think I really understand Java generics."

Nobody does...

The issue is related to the interesting return type of [`getClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29). See its javadoc. And [this recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589603/classlist-or-classlist).

In both of your examples, `lst.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends List>`, consequently, `newInstance()` returns `? extends List` - or more formally, a new type parameter `W` introduced by javac where `W extends List`

In your first example, we need to assign `W` to `List<Integer>`. This is allowed by [assignment conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2). First, `W` can be converted to `List` because `List` is a super type of `W`. Then since `List` is raw type, the optional unchecked conversion is allowed, which converts `List` to `List<Integer>`, with a mandatory compiler warning.

In the 2nd example, we need to assign `W` to `T`. We are out of luck here, there's no path to convert from `W` to `T`. It makes sense because as far as javac knows at this point, `W` and `T` could be two unrelated subclass of `List`.

Of course, we know `W` is `T`, the assignment would have been safe if allowed. The root problem here, is that `getClass()` loses type information. If `x.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends X>` without erasure, both of your examples will compile without even warning. They indeed are type safe.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are a way to guarantee type safety.
Eg:

```
int[] arr = new int[4];
   arr[0] = 4; //ok
   arr[1] = 5; //ok
   arr[2] = 9; //ok
   arr[3] = "Hello world"; // you will get an exception saying incompatible
```

types.

By default arrays in Java are typeSafe. An integer array is only meant to 
   contain integer and nothing else.

Now:

```
ArrayList arr2 =new ArrayList();
   arr2.add(4); //ok
   arr2.add(5); //ok
   arr2.(9); //ok


   int a = arr2.get(0);
   int b = arr2.get(1);
   int c = arr3.get(2);
```

You willa gain get an exception like what it is not possible to cast Object 
   instance to integer.

The reason is that ArrayList stores object and not primitive like the 
   above array.

The correct way would be to explicitly cast to an integer.You have to do this
   because type safety is not yet guaranteed.
   eg:

int a = (int)arr2.get(0);

To employ type safety for collections, you simply specify the type of objects that your collection contains.
 eg:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();


After insertion into the data structure, you can simply retrieve it like you 
would do with an array.
```

eg:

int a = arr2.get(0);